# Binance websocket API sends opcode 8 (connection close) 1 second after successful connect & transfer

Tags: websocket, binance

I'm having a problem with Binance's websocket API closing the connection almost immediately. The connect and websocket upgrade succeeds, and there's (usually) some of the expected data sent back, but the remote end sends websocket opcode 8 (connection close) less than a second after subscribing. Here's some example debug output; note the time between the initial connect and then reconnect is <= 1 second.

```
*** Connecting to server: stream.binance.com at 2021-05-25 16:06:48 UTC+0
websocket: connecting to ssl://stream.binance.com:9443 with path /ws/btcusdt@trade
websocket: connected
websocket: sent upgrade request
websocket: successful upgrade
Sending message to server: '{"method":"SUBSCRIBE","params":["btcusdt@trade"],"id":1}'
{"e":"trade","E":1621958809390,"s":"BTCUSDT","t":871186927,"p":"37950.99000000","q":"0.08750200","b":6146242615,"a":6146242639,"T":1621958809389,"m":true,"M":true}
{"e":"trade","E":1621958809390,"s":"BTCUSDT","t":871186928,"p":"37948.01000000","q":"0.27946700","b":6146242632,"a":6146242639,"T":1621958809389,"m":true,"M":true}

errstr=Remote sent opcode 8 (close)

*** Connecting to server: stream.binance.com at 2021-05-25 16:06:49 UTC+0
websocket: connecting to ssl://stream.binance.com:9443 with path /ws/btcusdt@trade
websocket: connected
websocket: sent upgrade request
websocket: successful upgrade
Sending message to server: '{"method":"SUBSCRIBE","params":["btcusdt@trade"],"id":1}'
{"e":"trade","E":1621958810172,"s":"BTCUSDT","t":871186935,"p":"37945.47000000","q":"0.00561300","b":6146242792,"a":6146242898,"T":1621958810171,"m":true,"M":true}
{"e":"trade","E":1621958810172,"s":"BTCUSDT","t":871186936,"p":"37945.43000000","q":"0.01233600","b":6146242721,"a":6146242898,"T":1621958810171,"m":true,"M":true}
{"e":"trade","E":1621958810183,"s":"BTCUSDT","t":871186937,"p":"37945.43000000","q":"0.00140200","b":6146242721,"a":6146242907,"T":1621958810183,"m":true,"M":true}
{"e":"trade","E":1621958810199,"s":"BTCUSDT","t":871186938,"p":"37945.36000000","q":"0.00484000","b":6146242644,"a":6146242914,"T":1621958810199,"m":true,"M":true}
{"e":"trade","E":1621958810203,"s":"BTCUSDT","t":871186939,"p":"37945.36000000","q":"0.08219200","b":6146242644,"a":6146242916,"T":1621958810203,"m":true,"M":true}
{"e":"trade","E":1621958810204,"s":"BTCUSDT","t":871186940,"p":"37945.36000000","q":"0.04644700","b":6146242644,"a":6146242917,"T":1621958810204,"m":true,"M":true}

errstr=Remote sent opcode 8 (close)
```

I'm using a simple PHP websocket client, slightly modified to output additional debug info: https://github.com/paragi/PHP-websocket-client , however the debug output above should be sufficient to show the subscribe process, and all other relevant parameters.

The same client works fine on another exchange's API.

I temporarily modified the client code to ignore opcode 8, but in that instance Binance enforces the close by closing the TCP socket.

I also tried this on a completely different server (located in another country, different ASN) in case it was my local IP/ASN that was the issue. Same problem.

Any ideas? I am new to websockets, and the Binance API, so perhaps I've done something silly. Thanks for any assistance.

EDIT: Here is minimal code to demonstrate the error. Requires https://github.com/paragi/PHP-websocket-client.git

Note: if there's no data returned, try running it a few times. Results are not consistent.

```
  require_once("PHP-websocket-client/websocket_client.php");
//   git clone https://github.com/paragi/PHP-websocket-client.git

$server = "stream.binance.com";
$serverport = 9443;
$streamname = "btcusdt@trade";
$t = array("method" => "SUBSCRIBE", "params" => array("$streamname"), "id" => 1);
$uri = "/ws/$streamname";

$message = json_encode($t) . "\n";

echo "\n*** Connecting to server: $server at " . gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s") . " UTC+0\n";

$sp = websocket_open($server, $serverport,'',$errstr, 30, true, false, $uri);

if ($sp) {
  echo "Sending message to server: '" . trim($message) . "' \n";
  websocket_write($sp,$message);
  while (1) {
    $r = websocket_read($sp,$errstr);
    echo "$r\n";
    if ($r == "") {
      echo "errstr=$errstr\n";
      die;
    }
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show your PHP code using of the library (redact any sensitive data such as API key/secret). It's possible that you're performing the authentication in a wrong way and Binance halts the connection as soon as it receives an unauthenticated message.

Comment: @PetrHejda It's a public stream AFAIK, so no authentication required. I have updated the question with the minimal amount of code required to show the issue.